# How to get the base dimensions of an object (ignoring all of it's modifiers)?

Tags: python, scripting, transforms, scale, dimensions

I'm trying to code a function that gets the base dimensions of an object that has multiple modifiers applied.

Sure, I can turn all the modifiers off, get the dimensions and then re-enable everything, but I'm wondering if anyone knows a different solution.

I tried with the bounding box but that is also affected by the modifiers. I also tried using the mesh data `object.data.dimensions` but meshes don't seem to have the "dimensions" attribute.

Any ideas, elegant or otherwise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Look at the mesh coordinates.**

The unmodified dimensions of the mesh can be obtained from the mesh.

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data

coords = np.empty(3 * len(me.vertices))
me.vertices.foreach_get("co", coords)
x, y, z = coords.reshape((-1, 3)).T

mesh_dim = (
        x.max() - x.min(),
        y.max() - y.min(),
        z.max() - z.min()
        )
        
print(mesh_dim)
```

Could use this to give a mesh a dimensions property

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty

def get_mesh_dims(self):
    coords = np.empty(3 * len(self.vertices))
    self.vertices.foreach_get("co", coords)

    x, y, z = coords.reshape((-1, 3)).T

    return (
            x.max() - x.min(),
            y.max() - y.min(),
            z.max() - z.min()
            )

bpy.types.Mesh.dimensions = FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Mesh Dimensions",
        get=get_mesh_dims,
        subtype='XYZ',
        unit='LENGTH',
        )
```

python console code, default cube, arrayed subsurfed spun and hung.

```
>>> C.object.data.dimensions
Vector((2.0, 2.0, 2.0))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain with so much detail. This will help me in so many ways. I didn’t know you could create custom properties like that. Bless you!

Comment: NP! Thanks, the feedback is appreciated. Scratch that re texture size, what was I thinking uses normalized size.