# The result of running the script is different from that of running the console

Tags: python

The console results are correct, The result of running the script is wrong

I want to know what the problem is and run it in the script

```
def func(listTemp, n):

    for i in range(0, len(listTemp), n):

        yield listTemp[i:i + n]  

def ins1():    

    a=bpy.data.meshes[0]

    b=bpy.data.objects

    d = [x for ob in bpy.data.objects for x in ob.dimensions]

    temp=func(d,3)

    e=[]

    for i in temp:

        e.append(i)

    for x,y in zip(b,e):

        x.dimensions=y

    for w in b:

        w.data=a
    
    return(e)

aa=ins1()

def ins2():

    b=bpy.data.objects

    for x,y in zip(b,aa):

        x.dimensions=y

    return

ins2()
```

Comment: What do you expect? Please elaborate on your goal: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Descriptive names of your functions and variables would also help us help you.

Comment: Very likely https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234020/exporting-data-looping-through-objects-gets-wrong-data-for-very-last-object/234068#234068 or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234254/setting-translation-overrides-scaling  running in the python console updates per line.  To reiterate advice in those answers is use scale not dimension.

Comment: Thank you very much. I found the reason  dimensions need "bpy.context.view_layer.update()", location,rotation,scale do not need.