# How to set the dimensions of an object without it's modifiers?

Tags: python, modifiers

I'm trying to set the size of an object without it's modifiers. So, in a script, I turn off the visible modifiers, then set the scale, then turn them back on. Why doesn't it work?

It does shrink the room and set correctly if I comment out the last:

```
show_modifiers_master_room(True)
```

But, when I turn the modifiers back on, the object's scale *includes* the modifier dimensions (I have a simple Solidify modifier on the object "Master Room"). It appears as if Blender is applying the dimensions *after* the modifiers are turned back on.

```
def show_modifiers_master_room(p_bool):
    ob = bpy.data.objects['Master Room']
    for mod in getattr(ob, "modifiers", []):
        mod.show_viewport = p_bool
    print ("show mods: " + str(p_bool))

def room_dim_changed_v(self, context):
    show_modifiers_master_room(False)
    bpy.data.objects['Master Room'].dimensions = (4.0,2.0,2.0)
    show_modifiers_master_room(True)
```

Comment: Very likely same issue as here.  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234020/exporting-data-looping-through-objects-gets-wrong-data-for-very-last-object

Comment: or via https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212926/how-to-get-the-base-dimensions-of-an-object-ignoring-all-of-its-modifiers/212929#212929

Comment: `C.scene.objects.get("Master Room")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Setting dimension requires a view layer update**

As outlined in [Exporting data: looping through objects gets wrong data for very last object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234020/exporting-data-looping-through-objects-gets-wrong-data-for-very-last-object)  call `view_layer.update()` after using dimensions, to set the scale.

**Get the dimensions from the mesh**

Borrowing from both

[How to get the base dimensions of an object (ignoring all of it's modifiers)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212926/how-to-get-the-base-dimensions-of-an-object-ignoring-all-of-its-modifiers/212929#212929)

[How do I get the bounding box of all objects in a scene](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/223858/how-do-i-get-the-bounding-box-of-all-objects-in-a-scene)

can get the unmodified global sized bounding box of a mesh

```
import bpy
import numpy as np
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty

def np_matmul_coords(coords, matrix, space=None):
    M = (space @ matrix @ space.inverted()
         if space else matrix).transposed()
    ones = np.ones((coords.shape[0], 1))
    coords4d = np.hstack((coords, ones))
    
    return np.dot(coords4d, M)[:,:-1]


def get_mesh_dims(self):
    if self.type != 'MESH':
        return None
    me = self.data
    coords = np.empty(3 * len(me.vertices))
    
    me.vertices.foreach_get("co", coords)

    x, y, z = np_matmul_coords(coords.reshape(-1, 3), self.matrix_world).T

    return (
            x.max() - x.min(),
            y.max() - y.min(),
            z.max() - z.min()
            )

bpy.types.Object.mesh_dimensions = FloatVectorProperty(
        name="Mesh Dimensions",
        get=get_mesh_dims,
        subtype='XYZ',
        unit='LENGTH',
        )
```

Now having run script above every object has a mesh dimension property. Here is a test run on default cube with default subdivision surface.

```
>>> C.object.mesh_dimensions
Vector((2.0, 2.0, 2.0))

>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> C.object.dimensions
Vector((1.6790125370025635, 1.6790125370025635, 1.6790125370025635))

>>> C.object.mesh_dimensions
Vector((2.0, 2.0, 2.0))

>>> d = C.object.mesh_dimensions
>>> C.object.scale = 4 / d.x, 4 / d.y, 4 / d.z
>>> C.object.scale
Vector((2.0, 2.0, 2.0))
```