# Can I get unsheared dimensions on an object?

Tags: python, transforms, dimensions

I would like to be able to get the original dimensions of an object after shear has been applied.  [image]

The dimensions of the new object are now different from the original cube.  Can I determine what the original dimensions are from Python?  I've read in other stack exchange questions that I can find the object's original size from the object's mesh (such as from this question:
[How to get the base dimensions of an object (ignoring all of it's modifiers)?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/212926/how-to-get-the-base-dimensions-of-an-object-ignoring-all-of-its-modifiers))  But when I look at the vertices of the mesh as explained in the answer, the vertices refer to the sheared object and not the original object.

Comment: How did you apply the shear? If you applied it with `A` > *Visual Geometry to Mesh*, there's no way to get the original dimensions unless you assume that the original shape was a cuboid with all angles equal to 90 degrees. Is that the assumption you are making? Then it should be solvable.

Comment: What will you do with the original dimensions once you shear the cube?

Comment: I am using bpy.ops.transform.shear to apply the shear.  I was thinking that I could possibly use the transform matrix to find the original dimensions of the cube.  Or, perhaps I could use a modifier to apply shear and then just temporarily remove the modifier.  I am using Blender to visualize geometry for a scientific simulation, which needs the original dimensions of the object (not necessarily a cube).

Comment: Would it be possible to use the inverse of the transformation matrix to get the original dimensions of the object and then reapply the transformation matrix?  I am not sure how to apply the steps to try this.  Or, I'll try to remove the shear, get the object dimensions, and then reapply it.